# Embedding python in C++

Tags: python, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to embedded a python function in a c++ node. I've read the documentation on docpython for Python 3.4 and I've tried a little example from  the doc :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <python3.4/Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ros::init(argc, argv, "fault_detector");
   Py_Initialize();
   PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                 "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
   Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

and i get this error :

```
CMakeFiles/ft_node.dir/src/fault_detector.cpp.o: In function `main': 
fault_detector.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
fault_detector.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
fault_detector.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
make[2]: *** [/home/mamy/exo_ws/devel/lib/test/ft_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/ft_node.dir/all] Error 2
```

I've done some research to find my problems but I can't find anything pertinent. It could be a problem of version as I read and i don't know how to change that. If anyone has an answer.

Thank you in advance for your answer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210293/embedding-python-in-c++/) by [bulgrozer](https://answers.ros.org/users/22356/bulgrozer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like a linker error... Have you added the somehing like the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`?

```
find_package (PythonLibs 3.4 EXACT)

target_link_libraries(fault_detector ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2015-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2